# No output after running opencv cascade command

Tags: python, opencv, cascade-classifier

I am trying to make a cascade after a tutorial on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XrCAvs9AePM&list=PL1m2M8LQlzfKtkKq2lK5xko4X-8EZzFPI&index=9)(at this point I am at minute 18:30z) and everything up until this point is working, but if I run the command:

```
D:/OpenCV/build/x64/vc15/bin/opencv_traincascade.exe -data 008_cascade_classifier/cascade -vec pos.vec -bg 008_cascade_classifier/neg.txt -w 300 -h 300 -numPos 200 -numNeg 100 -numStages 10
```

I get no output, no error, no success.
Here's how the output looks in full:

```
PS C:\Users\VM\Documents\GitHub\opencv_tutorials> D:/OpenCV/build/x64/vc15/bin/opencv_traincascade.exe -data 008_cascade_classifier/cascade -vec pos.vec -bg 008_cascade_classifier/neg.txt -w 300 -h 300 -numPos 200 -numNeg 100 -numStages 10
PS C:\Users\VM\Documents\GitHub\opencv_tutorials>
```

I have checked and paths are correct, I even put the absolute path, still the same result. I also built pos.vec multiple times but it tells me:

```
PS C:\Users\VM\Documents\GitHub\opencv_tutorials> D:/OpenCV/build/x64/vc15/bin/opencv_createsamples.exe -info 008_cascade_classifier/pos.txt -w 300 -h 300 -num 1000 -vec pos.vec
Info file name: 008_cascade_classifier/pos.txt
Img file name: (NULL)
Vec file name: pos.vec
BG  file name: (NULL)
Num: 1000
BG color: 0
BG threshold: 80
Invert: FALSE
Max intensity deviation: 40
Max x angle: 1.1
Max y angle: 1.1
Max z angle: 0.5
Show samples: FALSE
Width: 300
Height: 300
Max Scale: -1
RNG Seed: 12345
Create training samples from images collection...
008_cascade_classifier/pos.txt(32) : parse errorDone. Created 46 samples
```

And it looks like it works since it tells me that it created the samples.

What is wrong?

Comment: What's in pos.txt line 32? It's saying that there is a parsing error?!?

Comment: Before there was a broken path there, so I deleted it. But even though I trained it after that I still get the same error.

Comment: You could try to debug by using a small and verified-ok subset of your pos-file

Comment: how can I do that? I deleted another line now it has 31 lines, so it tells me 008_cascade_classifier/pos.txt(31) : parse error

Comment: Is there an empty new line in the end? If yes, try to remove it. If no, try to add one.

Comment: Added it then ran, same error. Removed it same error.

Comment: Did you set -num 1000 to a value <= your working lines in your txt file? Can you share your txt file?

Comment: Here it is: https://pastebin.com/vQTbacy8